# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions showing serious error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext, xcode-6.2

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ClassCell *cell = (ClassCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    ...
}
```

*Upon the selection of collection view cell, this line causes errors:
(I added symbolic breakpoint  **CGPostError** to figure this out)*

```
> <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a
> serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
> invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
> of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. This
> is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using
> an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall
> degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a
> courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an
> upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a
> serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
> invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
> of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. This
> is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using
> an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall
> degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a
> courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an
> upcoming update.
> 
> <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Am i using this line wrong?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

I'm using Xcode 6.2

Comment: I think this line shouldn't be a problem,Please show the next line of codes.

Comment: Check if happens also on the device

Comment: Your cell has invalid size. E.g zero, negative or infinitely large. Check why that happens.

Comment: Thanks guys! but the cell has a valid size. Hmm what else could cause this..

Comment: If you are convinced the size is correct, then add some assertions there, will catch the error quickly enough. If that is indeed not the case, there's a whole thread related to this error and its appearance in iOS 7, it could be that as you added the breakpoint you are seeing errors from other parts of the system?